# Devops Export - Parent ID Description

Tags: azure-devops, devops

When exporting a Devops Query that contains Parent column (whether in  CSV/Email or simply by control + C key), the parent column values are displayed in the form of number IDs. Is there a way to display their actual descriptions instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.